# how to create a master design page then all other pages use that master design

Tags: php

i have a backend and im sick of copying the css, and design layout each time i create a new page. how can i easily keep a master design and every new page i create i can write whatever i want and it will use the master design and tabs that ive set?

i dont want to get into smarty or anything related to that because its gonna take time to learn it. is there another alternative preferably something easy and fast?

thanks

Comment: Could you ellaborate about the 'tabs that ive set' part?

Comment: "Copy the CSS"? - where from and where to? Do you mean *across projects*, or within the same site?

Comment: @Michael by tabs i meant navigation links.

Comment: @deceze both, across sites and the same site. relate my question to powerpoint if you've used it. you set a master design and every new page you create the design is incorporated.

Comment: If you're copying your CSS between pages within the same site, you're not using CSS correctly. Are you using external .css files or inline styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only PHP you could do something as simple as:

```
inlucude 'top_with_css_includes_and_all.php';

// do your page stuff here

include 'footer.php';
```

I suggest that you use a light weight framework if you find Smarty or other similar frameworks to cumbersome.

You could have a look at [Flourish](http://flourishlib.com) specifically the [fTemplate class](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fTemplating).

Comment: Agreed - this is what I do for small sites - a file for CSS, one for Javascript, one for header, one for footer etc. That way I can update any include if required.

Comment: thanks michael i have already done this where i keep all header stuff in header.php and it contains links to all the css and js that i use but i was wondering how the pros do it out there every time a new page is created some way some how the theme is incorporated. i guess their using a theming template but u never know.

Comment: If you put in a bit more details maybe there is more to it?!